# Add two values in 1 key in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can add two values in `':ID'` separated with dot. Values are numbers, i want `':ID'` to be like 1.2, 2.3 etc...

```
 $pdoExec = $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
                    ':ID' => $_SESSION['memberID'] "." $row['#'],
        ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `floatval` function to convert string to float value:

```
$pdoExec = $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
                    ':ID' => floatval($_SESSION['memberID']. "." .$row['#']),
        ) );
```

Comment: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "." (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in your code.
With this, it add two number but without dot. like 12 or 23
`:ID' => floatval($_SESSION['memberID'] . $row['#']),`

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski, yes, I see, check the updated fix

Comment: It's okay, fixed with two dots `. "." .` Thank you so much.